# Speeding up postgres queries in v12.1?

Tags: entity, sql, databases

New in v12.1 is the ability to connect to Postgres. I have a Postgresql database with a few million images (stored as byte data). Each image retrieval is ~10 seconds, so I need to speed it up! But how to speed this up, I don't think MMA has any way of doing threading?

**What I've tried:**

These are the steps I am using to connect and do the query:

```
ref=DatabaseReference[URL["postgres://<connection params>"]]
schema=RelationalDatabase[ref]    
store = EntityStore[schema]    
EntityRegister[store]    
screenshots=EntityList["screenshots"];
```

[image]

```
screenshotProperties = EntityProperties[screenshots[[1]]]
AbsoluteTiming[#->screenshots[[1]][#]&/@screenshotProperties//TableForm]
```

[image]

Comment: I lack access to any sort of Postgres database (or any other database, really) to test, but `SessionSubmit` lets you start asynchronous tasks on a separate kernel and use an event handling function when they finish. Perhaps that would help.

Comment: Sure, something to try but I don’t know if there are any more ways to handle multithreaded queries that need multiple database connections to unblock each other...

Comment: Indeed, 10Mb `ByteArray` could / should've been transferred faster. We will take a note / keep this use case in mind. I can't tell off hand, without testing, whether you can do anything simple enough on the WL top level to speed this up, but as I said, we will pay attention to this case and try to address this soon.